# Calling models from other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Two models in my Rails 4 app are - `Accommodation.rb` and `Account.rb` - each Accommodation `has_one` Account.

In my `Accommodation.rb` I have this method:

```
def my_method
  self.field = "Something"
  save!
end
```

and I call the method from the `AccommodationsController.rb` using:

```
accommodation.my_method
```

but I also need to be able to call a method in my `Account.rb` from my `Accommodation.rb` model whilst maintaining the association so that if I create or update a record in the Accounts table it will know which accommodation_id to reference. Something on the lines of:

```
Account.accommodation.my_other_method
```

but I know this won't work as it is a "stab in the dark"

**Note** I'm trying to keep my logic in my models

Comment: You may just call `@accommodation.account` and `@account.accommodation` for the associated record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reference an associated model (in order to call methods on it, for instance), you simply use the automatically generated method that matches the name of the model.

For instance, if Accommodation `has_one` Account, and `accommodation` is an Accommodation object, you can call `accommodation.account` to refer to the associated account. This reference can have methods called on it as normal: `accommodation.account.my_account_instance_method(foo)`

Alternatively, if you're in a method definition in Accommodation, you can refer to the method directly:

```
class Accommodation
  has_one :account

  def do_something
    account.my_account_instance_method
  end
end
```

All of this is pretty well documented in the [Rails associations basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), which I highly recommend you look through at least briefly.